# Mapping array indices to List with streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `boolean[]` and I want to turn into `List<Integer>`. Each item in the list will be an index of the `boolean[]` where that index must be `true`.
Right now I'm stuck with this code:

```
Stream.of(sieve)
        .filter(x->x.equals(true))
        .mapToInt(???)
        .collect(toList());
```

Any idea on how to accomplish this (with streams of course)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to introduce the indices to your `Stream` pipeline by using `IntStream::range`.

```
boolean[] sieve = sieve();
int[] numbers = IntStream.range(0, sieve.length).filter(i -> sieve[i]).toArray();
```

Or if you want a `List<Integer>` as result:

```
List<Integer> = IntStream.range(0, sieve.length).filter(i -> sieve[i])
                         .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```